# Cassandra RowKey Filter

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

If I have a few keys in my Cassandra column family in the form

```
ben-jhonson
niel-jhonson
kim-jhonson
George-Williams
Douglous-Peter
```

---etc

Is there any strategy to retrieve all names ending with Jhonson ?

Typically a sql query of the form `select * from tablename where name like '%Jhonson';`

What could be the cassandra alternative for the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra does not support LIKE queries.  If you need this sort of functionality, you can do this with a composite key of lastname:firstname.  This will allow you to query the last name component separately and get all firstnames that match.  Note that the lastname component MUST be the first in the list, because you have to supply at least one equals match.